# For each to find object in an array, and return that object

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

New here, got a small problem that is giving me a headache. I feel like its like one line of code to fix, but for the life of me I cant figure it out.

I'm supposed to have a for-each loop that locates an object within an array and returns that object if it exists, and returns null if it doesn't exist. Yet here's the odd thing for me, it can find the object just fine, and it will set it to something, not the object, just something. I can tell because other methods dependent on this work just fine, this one just isn't returning the object for whatever reason. Anyways, here's the code, I don't think you need anything else

```
   public Icosahedron findIcosahedron(String labelIn) {
      Icosahedron output;
      output = null;
      for (Icosahedron i : iList) {
         if (i.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn))  {
            output = i;
         }
      }
      return output;
   }
```

Requested:

```
 case 'F':
           System.out.print("\tLabel: ");
           label = userInput.nextLine();
           if (myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label) != null) {
               myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label);
           }
           else {
              System.out.println("\"" + label + "\" not found");
           }
           break;
```

Comment: how do you know it isn't returning the object?

Comment: @nupadhyaya I have another set of code that when you type in the label, it says something along the lines of 'it exists'  then it returns the object. Instead of that it just says the object exists then goes to the next bit in the loop

Comment: can you post that code

Comment: You're not assigning the output of myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label); to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't include a System.out.print() function for when the object is found, you run the function and do nothing with what it returns:

```
 case 'F':
           System.out.print("\tLabel: ");
           label = userInput.nextLine();
           if (myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label) != null) {
               myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label); // <- here
           }
           else {
              System.out.println("\"" + label + "\" not found");
           }
           break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you find object you should stop searching any further:

```
  for (Icosahedron i : iList) {
     if (i.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn))  {
        output = i;
        break;
     }
  }
```

Use `break` to leave the loop.

In the second part of your code store :

```
case 'F':
           System.out.print("\tLabel: ");
           label = userInput.nextLine();
           Icosahedron icosahedron = myIcosahedronList.findIcosahedron(label);
           if ( icosahedron == null) {
               System.out.println("\"" + label + "\" not found");
           }
           else {
              // Do something with icosahedron
           }
           break;
```

Comment: just `return i` and drop `output`.

Comment: I agree on that, but in order to do minimalistic changes and help OP to understand what is the reason, I changed this way.

Comment: Tried just that, but it didn't seem to take. Can't just return i for this assignment, because i need to to return null if it doesn't exist, unless i would hold null until it was assigned to something else?